# R and Encapsulation

Tags: r

I read that R does not allow encapsulation.  So when building a package/software for R, it is best to create folders that hold each of the functions, classes, and methods that work together.  I have a limited idea of encapsulation and thought that encapsulation would be a private function inside a function but I don't think that is the case.  More likely, encapsulation is used to hide internal functions from the user that the user need not bother with.  In this case then I think it is true that there is no encapsulation in R

I will be attempting to build my first package in week or so.  So, I have been reading documentation on building packages.  Is the above correct?

Also, I read that functions, classes and methods can be made available on start-up without building a package but there were no instructions on how to do it.  Is this true, because that would be very helpful.

Comment: It is definitely possible to have internal functions that users don't have direct access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't have encapsulation in the sense that objects can't have private members. If you do, for example,

```
obj <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
class(obj) <- "foo"
```

Then anyone can examine and even modify the contents of `obj` with `obj$a`, `obj$b`, and so on:

```
obj$a         # returns 1
obj$a <- 999  # 'a' component of obj now contains 999
```

This is distinct to encapsulation in the sense of separate namespaces, which R does have. When you build a package, you mark which of its functions are to be visible to the outside world using the `NAMESPACE` file. Everything not mentioned in there is by default invisible.

Comment: So, if there are processes that I don't want the user to see then I can leave those out of the namespace file?  I will read up on namespaces?  Thank-you